# How to add menuitems of different tabs in the actionbar?

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I am using a TabActivity in which i have 2 tabs with different activities.My app has total 3 activities.Two activities of the tabs and one activity is of the MainActivity. Now the problem    is that the actionbar is only showing the menuitems of the mainactivity in the actionbar. But i want to show the menuitems of the first tab activity also in the actionbar.

Comment: What You Have Done ??? Check Following Links

Comment: i dont want an actionbar with tabs. I want  different actionbar for different tabs( i m using tabactivity)...